# Changing the size of a simpledialog on tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'd like to know if it's possible to change the size of the window on my simpledialog to the values I want. Here's the code I want to use to change the values in my simpledialog:

```
def tipper(self, width=300, height=200):
    nom_tipper = simpledialog.askstring("Tipper", "Quel est votre nom ?")
    donation_tipper = simpledialog.askfloat("Tipper", "Combien voulez-vous donner ?")

    if nom_tipper is not None and donation_tipper is not None:
        date_actuelle = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        with open("liste_nom_tipper.txt", "a") as fichier:
            fichier.write(f"{date_actuelle} - {nom_tipper} a donné {donation_tipper}\n")
            self.nouveau_portefeuille_tippie += donation_tipper
```

I tried this:
`dialog = simpledialog.askstring(title="Test", prompt="Quel est votre nom ?", width=300, height=200)`
It still doesn't work.

Comment: You would have to define your own dialog window - a subclass of `simpledialog.Dialog`, perhaps.  None of the convenience functions like `askstring()` give you that level of control over the window.

Comment: Why do you want to change the size of the dialog? What do you expect on the layout of those widgets inside the dialog if the size of the dialog can be adjusted?